# Activity not registered in the manifest Lint warning

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-lint

I have a base activity from which I subclass several other activities.

Those other activities I do register in the manifest so I can use them from within my application.

However, Android inspection says, for my base activity, `"Activity not registered in the manifest"`.

I see no reason to register the base activity as I never use it directly. However, maybe, I am missing something and the warning should not be ignored?

Why this warning anyway?

Comment: My assumption is, that the Android Studio only checks, if the given class inherits from Activity or not. As far as I can say, there is no straightforward way for Android Studio to detect, if a class is a base class and is actually being(will be) used or not.

Comment: The only need to add activities to the manifest is to register the intents with the system so that your components, and other apps, can create an intent to launch the activity.  You could turn of the lint check or add the activity to your manifest or, just ignore it.

Comment: @Simon If I add my base Activity to the manifest can there be any unforeseen security risks?

Comment: Theoretically, you could create intents using class name strings, or other apps could use your Activity - in these cases, ignoring the warning would cause an exception.

Comment: I can't see why.  If you don't add an intent filter, then no external component can launch it, and even if it could, what could be the worst case?  Do you have a specific concern?

Comment: @Simon No, no specific concern, I've just read about the recent PreferenceActivity exploit so I thought maybe there's something. I see now, thank you.

Comment: @Simon Other components could still launch it with an [explicit intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleExplicit), unless you make it [not exported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll only need to list activities that are entry points to your app in the manifest. That is, activities that are invoked with an `Intent`.

You should not have activities that are in fact not instantiable entry points. Make such activity classes `abstract`. This will also get rid of the lint warning.

Comment: Ah, really. I didn't think about making them abstract, ha! Thanks.

Comment: I'm taking over a large chunk of code from elsewhere, how do I check if it can be invoked with an `intent`?

Answer (score 5):

You should make your BaseActivity as an Abstract class. No need to register such Activities in manifest, they are just simple java classes extending Activity class not an Activity of your application.

```
  public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());
    }

    protected abstract int yourmethods();
  }

 public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    // do extra stuff on your resources, using findViewById on your layout_for_activity1
}

   @Override
   protected int yourmethod() {
     //implemetation
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare in the manifest only the activities that user can see during its experience. Usually these are called by intents. The others you should declare abstract.